# External Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I'm working with an external jss library that will let me use a datepicker that doesn't cut off the previous and next months dates.  I'm getting an error when going through the coding.

code

```
$.fn.calendar = function (options) {
        var _this = this;
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.calendar.defaults, options);
        var week = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
        var tHead = week.map(function (day) {
            return "<th>" + day + "</th>";
        }).join("");

        _this.init = function () {
            var tpl = '<table class="cal">' +
            '<caption>' +
            '   <span class="prev"><a href="javascript:void(0);">&larr;</a></span>' +
            '   <span class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">&rarr;</a></span>' +
            '   <span class="month"><span>' +
            "</caption>" +
            "<thead><tr>" +
            tHead +
            "</tr></thead>" +
            "<tbody>" +
            "</tbody>" + "</table>";
            var html = $(tpl);
            _this.append(html);
        };
```

Here's the error:

```
var tHead = week.map(function (day) {

Object doesn't support property or method 'map'
```

I don't see why the map function is not supported on the array object.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your Array has no map method, which is part of ECMA-262 edition 5 and which your JS engine seems not to support? You can implement Array.prototype.map manually by taking it from somewhere like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.